# I encounter the following error when trying to run the code - error: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime

Tags: mysql

"What could be the cause of the error message 'strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime' when attempting to execute the code?"

I CANNOT RESOLVE THE FOLLOWING ERROR IN THE CODE

I encounter the following error when trying to run the code::

strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime

```
    @bot.command()
    async def ponto_status2(ctx, user_mention):
        # Certifique-se de que a conexão com o banco de dados esteja aberta
        try:
            if not conn:
                await ctx.send("Erro de conexão com o banco de dados.")
                return

            user_id = extract_user_id(user_mention)

            if user_id is None:
                await ctx.send("Por favor, mencione um usuário válido para verificar o histórico de patrulha.")
                return

            cursor = conn.cursor()

            # Execute as operações do banco de dados
            cursor.execute("SELECT user_id, patrol_count, total_hours FROM patrol_data WHERE user_id = %s", (user_id,))
            result = cursor.fetchone()

            if result is not None:
                # Acesse os valores dentro da linha de resultados
                user_id, patrol_count, total_hours = result

                member = ctx.guild.get_member(user_id)

                if member:
                    username = f"[❯❯] {member.display_name}"

                    # Recupere o histórico de patrulha por dia e hora
                    cursor.execute("SELECT day, start_time, end_time FROM patrol_history WHERE user_id = %s", (user_id,))
                    patrol_history = cursor.fetchall()

                    report = f"Histórico de Patrulha de {member.display_name}:\n\n"

                    for row in patrol_history:
                        day_str, start_time_str, end_time_str = row
                        day = day_str.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') if isinstance(day_str, datetime.date) else day_str  # Converta a data se não for uma string
                        start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                        end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

                        report += f"Data: {day}\n"
                        report += f"Início de Serviço: {start_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')}\n"
                        report += f"Quantidade de Patrulhas: {str(patrol_count)}\n"
                        report += f"Encerramento de Serviço: {end_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')}\n\n"

                    # Crie um arquivo de texto com o relatório
                    filename = f"{member.display_name}_ponto_status.txt"
                    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                        file.write(report)

                    # Envie o arquivo de texto
                    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
                        await ctx.send(f"Relatório de Patrulha de {member.display_name}", file=discord.File(file, filename=filename))
                else:
                    await ctx.send("Usuário não encontrado.")
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"Dados de patrulha não encontrados para {user_mention}.")

            # Feche o cursor
            cursor.close()

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)  # Imprima o erro para fins de depuração
```